# Handle events in SPWebPartManager

Tags: sharepoint

How do i handle events such as "WebPartMoving" and "WebPartMoved" in a page conataining webparts. The webpart manager tag is added to the master page. So i added the handler to code behind:

m.WebPartMoving += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartMovingEventHandler(m_WebPartMoved);

but it's not working...what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to create your own WebPartManager (derived from SPWebPartManager)  and try to override the method in the WebPartManager itself. It seems SPWebPartManager does not raise all events. ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7209b1cc-fc1c-4043-a26b-ac6e4fbbf870)) Just to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

SPWebPartManager is sealed!!